# How to prevent button link ( as a bootstrap button) inside of div ( as a bootstrap button) clicking parent button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<button class="list-group-item" type="button">
<a class="btn-sm btn-info" href="/internal-api/v1/guidances/connector-guidance" target="_blank">Second Button</a>
<div class="btn btn-primary ">Main Button </div>
</button>
```

Is there a way to prevent clicking on a link (Second Button) not to cause clicking Main Button?

Comment: You can't put links in buttons...it's invalid HTML

Comment: you can use jquery to prevent click of parent as clicked on clild

Comment: You dont want main button to be clicked at all?

Comment: I want it to be clicked any other time. Just not when second button is clicked

Comment: when you click seconde button it will take you to next page right?

Comment: It's for downloading file.

Comment: remove the type button from the parent

Answer (score -3):

```html
<div class="list-group-item" >
        <a class="btn-sm btn-info" href="/internal-api/v1/guidances/connector-guidance" target="_blank">Second Button</a>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button">Main Button </button>
        
        </div >
```

Change your code like this to avoid clicking parent button and style accordingly